# When trying to sign-in using Google auth, it says: OAuth - Error handling auth response. Error: Internal+server+error

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

My app have multiple environments (`dev`, `staging`, and `production`). I set up Google Sin-in in the `dev` environment and everything works fine. But when switched to the `staging` environment, it breaks. Click on Google sign-in > Click on the google account or sign-in to the google account > Re-direct to the app > The user does not get signed-in. When I check the console, it shows the following error:

```
next-dev.js?7fd2:24 [ERROR] 08:01.238 OAuth - Error handling auth response. Error: Internal+server+error.+
    at OAuth.eval (OAuth.js?ca4e:244:1)
    at step (OAuth.js?ca4e:55:1)
    at Object.eval [as next] (OAuth.js?ca4e:36:46)
    at eval (OAuth.js?ca4e:30:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (OAuth.js?ca4e:26:1)
    at OAuth.handleAuthResponse (OAuth.js?ca4e:220:1)
    at AuthClass.eval (Auth.js?134d:2271:1)
    at step (Auth.js?134d:55:1)
    at Object.eval [as next] (Auth.js?134d:36:46)
    at eval (Auth.js?134d:30:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (Auth.js?134d:26:1)
    at AuthClass._handleAuthResponse (Auth.js?134d:2233:1)
    at eval (Auth.js?134d:229:1)
    at eval (urlListener.js?d88e:17:1)
    at AuthClass.configure (Auth.js?134d:223:24)
    at eval (Amplify.js?b2f6:84:1)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at AmplifyClass.configure (Amplify.js?b2f6:83:1)
    at eval (configureAmplify.js?89ed:10:1)
    at ./configureAmplify.js (_app.js?ts=1660300676845:34680:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1660300676845:698:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1660300676845:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1660300676845:353:21)
    at eval (_app.js:12:75)
    at ./pages/_app.js (_app.js?ts=1660300676845:35758:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1660300676845:698:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1660300676845:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1660300676845:353:21)
    at eval (?9413:5:16)
    at eval (route-loader.js?7e94:215:51)
```

I tried to sign in using another Google account, tried different Google client credentials, updated Amplify auth and went through all the settings. Still nothing worked. I then checked the cloud watch logs. Nothing...

Any idea what's happening?

#### Log output

```
// Put your logs below this line
[DEBUG] 25:10.892 AuthClass - Error in cognito hosted auth response Error: Internal+server+error.+
    at OAuth.eval (OAuth.js?ca4e:244:1)
    at step (OAuth.js?ca4e:55:1)
    at Object.eval [as next] (OAuth.js?ca4e:36:46)
    at eval (OAuth.js?ca4e:30:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (OAuth.js?ca4e:26:1)
    at OAuth.handleAuthResponse (OAuth.js?ca4e:220:1)
    at AuthClass.eval (Auth.js?134d:2271:1)
    at step (Auth.js?134d:55:1)
    at Object.eval [as next] (Auth.js?134d:36:46)
    at eval (Auth.js?134d:30:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (Auth.js?134d:26:1)
    at AuthClass._handleAuthResponse (Auth.js?134d:2233:1)
    at eval (Auth.js?134d:229:1)
    at eval (urlListener.js?d88e:17:1)
    at AuthClass.configure (Auth.js?134d:223:24)
    at eval (Amplify.js?b2f6:84:1)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at AmplifyClass.configure (Amplify.js?b2f6:83:1)
    at eval (configureAmplify.js?89ed:10:1)
    at ./configureAmplify.js (_app.js?ts=1660301705941:34680:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:698:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:353:21)
    at eval (_app.js:12:75)
    at ./pages/_app.js (_app.js?ts=1660301705941:35758:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:698:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:353:21)
    at eval (?9413:5:16)
    at eval (route-loader.js?7e94:215:51)
instrument.js?1ea2:109 [DEBUG] 25:10.893 Hub - Dispatching to auth with  
{event: 'signIn_failure', data: Error: Internal+server+error.+
    at OAuth.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amp…, message: 'The OAuth response flow failed'}
data: Error: Internal+server+error.+ at OAuth.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:255:35) at step (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:66:23) at Object.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:47:53) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:41:71) at new Promise (<anonymous>) at __awaiter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:37:12) at OAuth.handleAuthResponse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:231:16) at AuthClass.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:2285:65) at step (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:69:23) at Object.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:50:53) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:44:71) at new Promise (<anonymous>) at __awaiter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:40:12) at AuthClass._handleAuthResponse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:2247:16) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:243:23) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/urlListener.js:19:9) at AuthClass.configure (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:237:69) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+core@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/lib-esm/Amplify.js:90:18) at Array.map (<anonymous>) at AmplifyClass.configure (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+core@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/lib-esm/Amplify.js:89:26) at eval (webpack-internal:///./configureAmplify.js:14:59) at ./configureAmplify.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1660301705941:34680:1) at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:698:31) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:37:33) at fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:353:21) at eval (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:12:75) at ./pages/_app.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1660301705941:35758:1) at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:698:31) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:37:33) at fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:353:21) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.2.2_cqi3zzjnvb643o7ixnrzsbv4xq/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?absolutePagePath=private-next-pages%2F_app&page=%2F_app!:5:16) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.2.2_cqi3zzjnvb643o7ixnrzsbv4xq/node_modules/next/dist/client/route-loader.js:247:16)
message: "Internal+server+error.+"
stack: "Error: Internal+server+error.+\n    at OAuth.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:255:35)\n    at step (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:66:23)\n    at Object.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:47:53)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:41:71)\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at __awaiter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:37:12)\n    at OAuth.handleAuthResponse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:231:16)\n    at AuthClass.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:2285:65)\n    at step (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:69:23)\n    at Object.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:50:53)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:44:71)\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at __awaiter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:40:12)\n    at AuthClass._handleAuthResponse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:2247:16)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:243:23)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/urlListener.js:19:9)\n    at AuthClass.configure (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:237:69)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+core@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/lib-esm/Amplify.js:90:18)\n    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n    at AmplifyClass.configure (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+core@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/lib-esm/Amplify.js:89:26)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./configureAmplify.js:14:59)\n    at ./configureAmplify.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1660301705941:34680:1)\n    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:698:31)\n    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:37:33)\n    at fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:353:21)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:12:75)\n    at ./pages/_app.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1660301705941:35758:1)\n    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:698:31)\n    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:37:33)\n    at fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:353:21)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.2.2_cqi3zzjnvb643o7ixnrzsbv4xq/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?absolutePagePath=private-next-pages%2F_app&page=%2F_app!:5:16)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.2.2_cqi3zzjnvb643o7ixnrzsbv4xq/node_modules/next/dist/client/route-loader.js:247:16)"
[[Prototype]]: Object
event: "signIn_failure"
message: "The OAuth response flow failed"
[[Prototype]]: Object

[DEBUG] 25:10.894 Hub - Dispatching to auth with  
{event: 'cognitoHostedUI_failure', data: Error: Internal+server+error.+
    at OAuth.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amp…, message: 'A failure occurred when returning to the Cognito Hosted UI'}
data: Error: Internal+server+error.+ at OAuth.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:255:35) at step (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:66:23) at Object.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:47:53) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:41:71) at new Promise (<anonymous>) at __awaiter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:37:12) at OAuth.handleAuthResponse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:231:16) at AuthClass.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:2285:65) at step (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:69:23) at Object.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:50:53) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:44:71) at new Promise (<anonymous>) at __awaiter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:40:12) at AuthClass._handleAuthResponse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:2247:16) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:243:23) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/urlListener.js:19:9) at AuthClass.configure (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:237:69) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+core@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/lib-esm/Amplify.js:90:18) at Array.map (<anonymous>) at AmplifyClass.configure (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+core@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/lib-esm/Amplify.js:89:26) at eval (webpack-internal:///./configureAmplify.js:14:59) at ./configureAmplify.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1660301705941:34680:1) at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:698:31) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:37:33) at fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:353:21) at eval (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:12:75) at ./pages/_app.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1660301705941:35758:1) at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:698:31) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:37:33) at fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:353:21) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.2.2_cqi3zzjnvb643o7ixnrzsbv4xq/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?absolutePagePath=private-next-pages%2F_app&page=%2F_app!:5:16) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.2.2_cqi3zzjnvb643o7ixnrzsbv4xq/node_modules/next/dist/client/route-loader.js:247:16)
message: "Internal+server+error.+"
stack: "Error: Internal+server+error.+\n    at OAuth.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:255:35)\n    at step (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:66:23)\n    at Object.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:47:53)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:41:71)\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at __awaiter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:37:12)\n    at OAuth.handleAuthResponse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/OAuth/OAuth.js:231:16)\n    at AuthClass.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:2285:65)\n    at step (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:69:23)\n    at Object.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:50:53)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:44:71)\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at __awaiter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:40:12)\n    at AuthClass._handleAuthResponse (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:2247:16)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:243:23)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/urlListener.js:19:9)\n    at AuthClass.configure (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+auth@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:237:69)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+core@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/lib-esm/Amplify.js:90:18)\n    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n    at AmplifyClass.configure (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-amplify+core@4.6.1/node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/lib-esm/Amplify.js:89:26)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./configureAmplify.js:14:59)\n    at ./configureAmplify.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1660301705941:34680:1)\n    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:698:31)\n    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:37:33)\n    at fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:353:21)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:12:75)\n    at ./pages/_app.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1660301705941:35758:1)\n    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:698:31)\n    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:37:33)\n    at fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1660301705941:353:21)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.2.2_cqi3zzjnvb643o7ixnrzsbv4xq/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?absolutePagePath=private-next-pages%2F_app&page=%2F_app!:5:16)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.2.2_cqi3zzjnvb643o7ixnrzsbv4xq/node_modules/next/dist/client/route-loader.js:247:16)"
[[Prototype]]: Object
event: "cognitoHostedUI_failure"
message: "A failure occurred when returning to the Cognito Hosted UI"

[DEBUG] 25:11.230 AuthClass - getting current authenticated user
instrument.js?1ea2:109 [DEBUG] 25:11.236 AuthClass - get current authenticated userpool user
instrument.js?1ea2:109 [DEBUG] 25:11.237 AuthClass - Failed to get user from user pool
instrument.js?1ea2:109 [DEBUG] 25:11.237 AuthClass - The user is not authenticated by the error No current user

[DEBUG] 25:11.238 Credentials - removing aws-amplify-federatedInfo from storage
instrument.js?1ea2:109 [DEBUG] 25:11.238 AuthClass - no current Cognito user
instrument.js?1ea2:109 [DEBUG] 25:11.238 Hub - Dispatching to auth with  
{event: 'signOut', data: null, message: 'A user has been signed out'}
data: null
event: "signOut"
message: "A user has been signed out"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```